# How can SortedList.add have o(log(n)) time complexity when it uses insort internally?

Tags: python, sortedcontainers

In sortedContainers it is specified that `SortedList.add` has approximately O(log(n)) time complexity, but we can see that it uses `insort()` in the source code, which is O(n):

```py
    def add(self, value):
        """Add `value` to sorted list.
        Runtime complexity: `O(log(n))` -- approximate.
        >>> sl = SortedList()
        >>> sl.add(3)
        >>> sl.add(1)
        >>> sl.add(2)
        >>> sl
        SortedList([1, 2, 3])
        :param value: value to add to sorted list
        """
        _lists = self._lists
        _maxes = self._maxes

        if _maxes:
            pos = bisect_right(_maxes, value)

            if pos == len(_maxes):
                pos -= 1
                _lists[pos].append(value)
                _maxes[pos] = value
            else:
                insort(_lists[pos], value)

            self._expand(pos)
        else:
            _lists.append([value])
            _maxes.append(value)

        self._len += 1
```

Can someone explain why the method still approximates to O(log(n)) despite the use of `insort` ?

Comment: See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) for reasons **not** to do it.

Comment: @martineau I don't get your comment since I have not uploaded images for this question.

Comment: Linking to them is equivalent. The idea is to put stuff *in* your question.

Comment: Ok, I added the code directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, from what I see in the code, SortedList uses set of lists to store the sorted list. The `add` first finds the relevant sublist and then inserts into it with `insort`, so it's linear on the length of the sublist, not the whole list. I suspect SortedList tries to keep length of each of the sublists bounded by `log(whole list)`.